# Сочетание многоточия и двоеточия, если многоточие обозначает пропуск

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие, цитата, многоточие

Если многоточие в цитате обозначает пропуск, а за этим пропуском идёт двоеточие, то как их сочетать?
К примеру, вот текст: *"Я подошёл к двери и спросил вполголоса: «Кто там?!»"*
А вот цитата: *"Я подошёл к двери и спросил...: «Кто там?!»"*
Верен ли в цитате порядок знаков? Не должно ли двоеточие стоять перед многоточием? **И ещё:** не должна ли одна точка из многоточия поглощаться двоеточием, то есть ":.." или "..:" писаться?

Comment: А вы не могли бы привести РЕАЛЬНЫЙ КОНТЕКСТ, где используется такая конструкция. Тогда многое прояснилось бы, в том числе обоснованность такого оформления.  Иначе все ответы будут условными, и умозрительными.  Почему это именно цитата, кто кого и зачем цитирует? Мне это непонятно.

Comment: @Sharon я уже не найду, откуда вытащил этот вопрос. В какой-то биографии журнальной встретил.

Comment: Ой-ёй! Спасибо, конечно! А почему вы так поторопились? А вдруг что-то еще найдется или кто-то захочет ответить?..

Comment: А почему вы тогда вообще об этом спрашиваете – вероятно, хотите применить это где-то на практике? И если не помните, тогда сами придумайте ситуацию (как бы для наглядности).  Тогда всем будет намного яснее – и вам, и нам.

Comment: @Sharon, так в вопросе присутствует наглядный пример.

Comment: Меня интересует контекст, чтобы понять, зачем здесь цитирование.  Одного предложения недостаточно. Впрочем, как я понимаю,  вопрос закрыт, проблема решена.

Comment: @Sharon закрыт, но не потому, что проблема решена, а потому, что её однозначно решить, по-видимому, не представляется возможным с нынешними правилами.

Comment: @Sharon Человек цитирует другого и хочет убрать "лишние" слова, от изъятия которых не пострадает основная мысль цитируемого. Эти слова стоят перед двоеточием в исходном тексте. Отсюда и вопрос: что делать с этим двоеточем.

Comment: Nektoid, спасибо еще раз! Задали задачку... Давно так долго не копался в одном вопросе!

Comment: Вероятно, такой пропуск нельзя обозначать многоточием. Это первое, что приходит в голову. Мне тогда больше нравятся угловые скобочки. Там любому человеку понятно, что это пропуск. А многоточие и паузу может обозначать...  Почему скобочки нельзя? Вот я гляжу на данный ответ – и ничего не понимаю в его оформлении. Я точно  думала, что там пауза какая-то.

Comment: @Sharon Так вот в этом-то тоже загвоздка (посмотрите P. S. в моем ответе). Я бы тоже как-то их разделял на письме, только правила говорят, что в угловых заключаются целые предложения и абзацы.

Comment: В ПАС есть пример собственно в правилах, где в угловые скобки помещено всего 5 слов (и даже одно!). *Вскоре дорога наша определилась, мы едем по правому высокому берегу реки; сквозь неодетые лиственные и разные хвойные деревья виднеется внизу широкая долина Тоймы* (Пришв.). — *Мы едем по правому высокому берегу реки: сквозь <...> деревья виднеется внизу <...> долина Тоймы*... (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144, § 163) Так что в **нестандартной** ситуации **можно** поставить угловые скобочки, можно — не мудрствуя лукаво.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова справочник Лопатина известен склонностью к некоторому упрощению ради унификации, но в данном случае, пожалуй, можно с ним согласиться. Хотя не понимаю, зачем городить угловые скобки, ведь достаточно просто отбить многоточие от предшествующего слова пробелом -- и уже станет понятно, что оно не авторское, а обозначает купюру (ведь нет иного случая, чтобы многоточие отбивать пробелом и от предшествующего, и от последующего слова).

Comment: Да, и еще: посмотрите на предложение Пришвина с переборами. Жаль, он не знал, что *два прилагательных при существительном в четыре раза хуже, чем одно*. Бедный, безграмотный  Пришвин, не имеющий ни стиля, ни мастерства.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова согласен, убого. Тот же Чехов, будучи даже старше Пришвина, куда лучше писал. Но в любом случае то, что было хорошо сто или семьдесят лет назад, нехорошо сейчас. На классиков в стиле равняться не надо. Если бы Пушкин стилистически равнялся на, к примеру, Тредиаковского, никогда бы не создал современный литературный русский язык. Попробуйте немного помыслить вне шаблонов, вдолбленных типичными училками в типичных школах, и вы эти простые истины осознаете. Вероятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала ответ.
***«Я подошёл к двери и спросил... "Кто там?!"»***
И сразу небольшое отступление от темы: «...рекомендуется использовать кавычки разного рисунка: внешние – «елочки», внутренние – „лапки”...» (**О кавычках внутри кавычек**, [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/89-kav)). Хотя, думаю, если в источнике прямая речь была в «ёлочках», то можно и наоборот.

Если возник такой вопрос, да ещё и объявлен конкурс, значит, информации об этом недостаточно или она не совсем ясно сформулирована, а Вы наверняка изучили материал по теме и, может быть, видели раздел «[**8.5. Многоточие как знак пропуска текста в цитате**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091470.html#id-8%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-85%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5)» (orfogrammka.ru).

> **8.5.1. Замена многоточием других знаков препинания**
> Многоточие заменяет такие знаки препинания перед опускаемым текстом в цитате, как запятая, двоеточие, точка с запятой, тире. Недопустимо заменять одну из точек многоточия каким-либо из этих знаков или сочетать многоточие с любым из них.

В этом правиле смущает только одно: "...знаки препинания ***перед*** опускаемым текстом..."
У нас же двоеточие стоит ***после***.
Зато есть ответ на последний вопрос, и я уверен, что точка из многоточия, обозначающего пропуск текста, не должна поглощаться двоеточием, ведь это не сочетание знаков типа "?..", "!..".

Но всё-таки дальше в этом правиле приводится пример, показывающий, как мне кажется, решение основного вопроса:

> ***В источнике:*** А поэзия, прости господи, должна быть глуповата.
> ***Правильно в цитате:*** «А поэзия... должна быть глуповата», —
> писал Пушкин.
> ***Неправильно в цитате:*** «А поэзия..., должна быть...»

Как видим, неправильно оставлять не только запятую, стоящую **перед** исключёнными словами, но и запятую **после** них.
Двоеточие, конечно, сильный знак, и я поначалу думал о таком варианте:
***"Я подошёл к двери и спросил... : «Кто там?!»"*** (с пробелом между знаками, и уж никак не с переменой их мест), но картинка вырисовалась, когда под конец поисков вот что встретилось на [Грамоте.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F.):

> ...поглощается ли знак препинания, следующий за многоточием вместо пропущенного (загаданного) слова? Например, в таком предложении. Дан приказ: ему на запад... Если опустить слово приказ, как это будет выглядеть? Дан ... ему на запад. Или. Дан ... : ему на запад.
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Двоеточие не сохраняется. Многоточие не только указывает на пропуск слов в тексте, но и на пропуск знаков препинания, таких как запятая, двоеточие, тире.

И никаких оговорок по поводу "до" и "после".

P. S. Для меня остаётся непонятным, как отличить многоточие в качестве пропуска текста в цитате от многоточия, используемого в источнике.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. // В примере из Мильчина вопросов нет: там изымается целиком вставная конструкция, и понятно, что отгораживающие её запятые остаются не нужны. В моём же случае изъятие слова перед двоеточием не отменяет необходимость двоеточия, вот в чём дело. К тому же мне не совсем ясно даже то, почему "Многоточие заменяет [двоеточие] перед опускаемым текстом", если вполне может писаться так: ***текст:** Я увидел следующее: неспешно шагали солдаты*. ***Цитата:** Я увидел следующее: ...шагали солдаты.* Здесь вроде как всё уместно выглядит.

Comment: Пример из Грамоты тоже не знаю, можно ли считать ответом в общем, а не частном случае. Во-первых, там удалено слово "приказ", которое, собственно, и "вводит" двоеточие, то есть без этого слова явно наличествует структурная каверна (а в моём примере при удалении "вполголоса" структурной каверны не возникает); во-вторых, в ответе сказано, что многоточие указывает на пропуск знаков препинания, но не сказано, *должны* ли эти знаки *непременно* удаляться при использовании многоточия как купюры в цитате.

Comment: @Nektoid  Ну что ж... Пока я сделал такие выводы на основании того, что нашёл... С двоеточием, конечно, было бы логичнее, но пишут, что заменяется. // Вставная конструкция из примера изымается целиком, да. А вот такое, например: ***текст:** Приехав в город рано утром, я сразу пошёл к ним. **Цитата:** Приехав в город... я сразу пошёл к ним.* // Грамота, согласен, часто отвечает очень поверхностно и не чётко. Всё же в данном случае, думаю, можно сказать, что речь идёт именно о купюре соответственно заданному вопросу.

Comment: да, в этом вашем примере запятая выглядела бы неуместно после многоточия. Я думаю, вы правы в своём ответе, но в целом в правилах, как видно, не проработаны разные варианты сочетаний многоточия и других пунктуационных знаков. Вот в соседнем вопросе Sharon задалась вопросом о знаке "...?" — и вполне резонно. Если многоточием отмечено, к примеру, нецензурное слово, после которого должен стоять вопрос, то как тогда писать? "Он и впрямь послал тебя на ...?" Между вопросом словом пробел не ставится, а между многоточием, обозначающим слово, и вопросом?..

Comment: @Nektoid Да, я тоже написал здесь коммент об этом, потом удалил. По крайней мере,  вопр. и воскл. знаки не указаны в правиле о замене купюрой, то есть они должны сохраняться – логика и здравый смысл налицо, и многоточие нужно ставить **перед** ними. Только вот как, с пробелом или без, – об этом ни слова.

Answer (score 1):

«Я подошёл к двери и спросил <...>: "Кто там?!"»

Многоточие вне скобок перед двоеточием выглядит и является частью цитируемог текста.

Comment: Вот если не знаете даже, как многоточием отмечать по правилам пропуски в тексте, зачем отвечаете? В цитатах используется обычное, ничем не отграниченное многоточие (см., например, http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg141.php пункт *б*).Многоточие в угловых скобках ставится там, где пропущен значительный кусок текста, от предложения и больше (см., например, https://publishing_dictionary.academic.ru/1630/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)

Comment: Это у вас и происходит: слов несколько, целый оборот.

Comment: Цитирую то, что по ссылке: "МНОГОТОЧИЕ В УГЛОВЫХ СКОБКАХ — знак, которым принято обозначать пропуск нескольких или даже больше фраз в докум. тексте или цитате". Ну и утверждение "Многоточие вне скобок перед двоеточием... является частью цитируемого текста" ложно. Так что минус и до свиданья.

Comment: Ждём приемлемого решения придуманной проблемы.

Comment: К сожалению, не придуманная. Я с ней столкнулся. Изменю вопрос, чтобы не было соблазна у кого-то ещё списать решение на многоточие в угловых скобках.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ второй

**Многоточие или многоточие в скобках? Общие рассуждения на тему**

1. **Многоточие**

Многоточие – знак серьезный, со многими функциями. Оно числится в правилах наряду с основными знаками, а о его значении говорится **в шести пунктах:** (1) незаконченность высказывания, (2) перерыв в речи, заминки, (3) неполное перечисление (4) неожиданный переход от одной мысли к другой; (5) продолжение прерванного повествования (в начале абзаца), (6) перечисление слов с нераскрытым содержанием.

Нагрузка впечатляет! Но многоточие еще используется и **при цитировании**. Если цитата приводится не полностью, то пропуск текста обозначается многоточием, которое ставится в начале, в середине или в конце цитаты.

**Как различить эти функции?** В примерах Розенталя цитаты выглядят весьма определенно: оформляются в виде прямой речи со словами автора (Толстой писал, Чехов вспоминал). Но есть и более сложные варианты оформления цитат – встроенные цитаты, например.

Вероятно, **наложение функций** многоточия весьма нежелательно, и поэтому мы должны использовать неполное цитирование так, чтобы структура предложения была ясна читателю.

Кроме того,  проблему **осложняют знаки, примыкающие** к пропущенной части текста. Здесь нужна **дополнительная регламентация**, так как многоточие может поглощать эти знаки или взаимодействовать с ними. С этой точки зрения это **не очень удобный знак**.

Но его достоинством является **компактность**, так как оно не отбивается пробелом от текста, поэтому многоточие используют в небольших по объему предложениях и при незначительных пропусках текста.

Справочная книга редактора и корректора http://www.az-print.com/FAQ/HelpBook/h011.shtml

2. **Многоточие в скобках**

Такого знака нет в правилах, поэтому его следует назвать **оформительским**. Его использование регламентируют в издательском словаре-справочнике. [https://publishing_dictionary.academic.ru/1630/Многоточие_в_угловых_скобках](https://publishing_dictionary.academic.ru/1630/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)

«Многоточие в угловых скобках — знак, которым принято обозначать пропуск **нескольких или даже больше фраз** в докум. тексте или цитате.

Набирают этот знак **с отбивкой** от предшествующего и последующего текста, сохраняя предшествующую точку, многоточие или вопросительный (восклицательный) знак, если предшествующий текст заканчивается ими, и сохраняя многоточие после М. в у. с. (обозначает пропуск слов в начале следующей фразы)».

Итак, достоинством этого знака является **ясность и однозначность** его функции, к тому же он точно уж не взаимодействует с другими знаками препинания. Однако у многоточия в скобках есть и **существенные недостатки** – он громоздкий, то есть занимает много места.  Знак сам по себе объемный, да еще отбивается пробелами с двух сторон. Ясно, что в небольших предложениях он будет неуместен.

3. **Выбор знака**

Как же выбрать нужный вариант?  Подсказка уже дана: для многоточия в скобках – это пропуск нескольких или даже больше фраз. И это не формальное правило, которое нужно неукоснительно соблюдать, а **разумное решение**. Автор должен сам ориентироваться, что именно подходит для его текста.

Особенный интерес представляют **сложные и нестандартные** по структуре цитаты, то есть различные частные случаи. Здесь ясность содержания должна быть на первом месте, поэтому выбор делается по этому критерию. Соответственно, мы можем использовать многоточие в скобках даже тогда, когда пропускаем всего несколько слов. Поэтому область применения этого знака должна быть **расширена**. Впрочем, это уже реально делается на практике.

4. **Нужно же ли ждать новых правил на эту тему**

Как мне кажется, нужно регламентировать использование многоточия в скобках **в основных** (не только издательских)  правилах, а также четко прописать использование обычного многоточия **при наличии других знаков.** Все это есть в ведомственных справочниках, но материал там изложен недостаточно ясно, а главное, очень мало реальных, а не надуманных кем-то примеров.

И конечно, возможность **авторского решения** при выборе знаков должна быть обозначена.

Comment: Я писал где-то выше и повторюсь: можно использовать вместо громоздкого многоточия в скобках просто многоточие, отбитое и от предшествующего слова, и от последующего. Насколько я знаю, во всех случаях многоточие должно "прилипать" либо к тому, либо у другому слову. Таким образом, "свободно висящее" многоточие и не выглядит громоздко, и вполне однозначно читается как знак купюры. // Лично я лишь в одном месте использовал многоточие с пробелами вокруг, это было необходимо для ощущения растяжения времени: "Вдох. Раз, два; три; четыре… пять… … …до лиловых кругов перед глазами, до судорог в лёгких".

Comment: Я думаю, что это половинчатое решение. Текст оно значительно не улучшит, а проблемы создаст. Корректор вам напишет, чтобы вы убрали пробелы. И взаимодействие с другими знаками так и останется. Здесь надо что-то принципиально другое. Может, круглые скобки использовать, тогда функция пропуска будет ясно обозначена. Мне графика многих вариантов не нравится – всё это множество точек с не всегда ясным значением.  То ли пропуск при цитировании обозначен, то ли персонаж заикается. И еще интересно: почему пробелы при угловых скобках отбиваются, а для обычного многоточия – нет.

Comment: Ну вот в лопатинском справочнике, насколько я понял, именно и предлагается любой пропуск обозначать многоточием в угловых скобках. Ок, но тогда должно ли от него отбиваться двоеточие в моём варианте? По правилам — нет, т.к. не существует причины, чтобы двоеточие висело в отрыве от предшествующего слова. Получается: *"Я подошёл к двери и спросил <...>: «Кто там?!»"* Не уверен, что это выглядит достаточно читабельно. Лично я вообще смайлик вижу в кобинации из второй угловой скобки и двоеточия.

Comment: Прекрасно выглядит,  читабельнее и быть не может: максимум понимания при "минимальных  умственных затратах" как для автора, так и для читателя. Если это лопатинская идея, тогда он хоть что-то стоящее предложил! Функции двух знаков разделены, значение их понятно.  (А смайлику забавно, что вы так долго искали нужное вам решение.)  В общем, идея хорошая: не надо искать себе трудностей там, где их нет.  Обозначен пропущенный текст, а все остальное остается без изменения.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поставила **многоточие в угловых скобках** как авторский вариант оформления.

Да и правило это (о пропуске целых абзацев и предложений) – **оформительское**, а это другой уровень по сравнению с правилами пунктуации. [https://publishing_dictionary.academic.ru/1630/Многоточие_в_угловых_скобках](https://publishing_dictionary.academic.ru/1630/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)

**Авторский вариант** использования скобок – это самое простое и наглядное решение Очевидно, что скобки (даже не по правилам) смотрятся и понимаются намного лучше и понятнее.

Прочитала **правило для двоеточия** (8.5.1. Замена многоточием других знаков препинания), и вот что поняла. Там речь идет об обычном двоеточии в предложении, а у нас особый случай – **предложение с прямой речью** и, соответственно, вторыми кавычками.

Поэтому здесь требуется **нестандартное решение**, и многоточие в скобках – это лучший вариант.